# Web access dataset with IP addresses

Tags: geolocation, dataset

I'm looking for a dataset that has information about web page access based on IP (could be anonymized) or Geo location. I noticed that neither the stackoverflow or wikipedia open-sourced datasets include this information.
Specifically, I'm looking for how many reads/writes are done on a webpage based on geo-location

Is there any public dataset that provides this information?

Comment: I don't understand your questions? Are you looking for web analytics like Google Analytics or geolocation database like IP2Location?

Comment: Suppose a website had 10 pages, I'd like dataset that tells me, page 1 was accessed or written by IP1 (or longitude-latitude) at time t1, page 2 was accessed or written by IP2 (or longitude-latitude) at time t2, etc.

Comment: So you are looking at the Google Analytics right?